# CSS and jQuery Simple Question

Tags: jquery, html, css

Just starting using css and jQuery and I have a CSS class called `.content` which I'm using for a side of the page navigation box, picture of the day box, statistics box, etc., which are layed out using a definition lists.

So I need it when I click on the `<dt>` tag it slides up/down the `<ul>` tag underneath it which is simple enough. but how do I determine which which instance of the `.content` class was clicked on... I know seperate id's would work but was wondering if there is a quicker way? Hope I explained my problem clear enough any help would be greatly appricated =]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A little HTML example would really help...

Comment: "`<dt>` tag it slides up/down the `<ul>`" Shouldn't that be `dd`?

Answer (score 3):

When you're inside a [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler (or any event handler), `this` refers to the current element, so you would do this:

```
$(".content").click(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
  //or possibly..
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Where `$(".content")` inside would again select all of them (sounds like your current issue), `this` refers to the DOM element that was clicked, so you can just do whatever action you want to it specifically.

Comment: Yeah i did try that mate but my problem is i need something like ` $(".content").click(function() {
  $(this + "ul").dosomething();
});` Which doesnt work for me :<

Comment: @Shiverz - I updated the answer to show how this is done, if it's a child, use `.find()`, or it's a sibling, use `.next()` :)

Comment: @Shiverz - welcome :) and welcome to SO!, be sure to accept answers on this and future questions, it'll make future ones more appealing to would-be answerers :)

Answer (score 0):

Specify using $(this) within your function for the selected class.  That will then use the correct class clicked on. For example:

```
$('.content').click(function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

This is obviously in it's simplest form and you can expand from there.